# Drawing a simple graph in overleaf/LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, graphs

i am trying to create the following graph in Overleaf:

[image: simple graph]

I have seen many questions on related sites of people asking similar questions with different types of graphs, however i can't find anything on graphs this simple. The examples I've seen are mainly on weighted graphs which i don't have.

I am a beginner with Overleaf and Latex so any help here would be appreciated.

I don't mind about the general shape of the graph, as long as the edges and nodes remain.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? This site is not a service "do-it-for-me"  ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here is a quick tutorial using the basics of Ti*k*Z.

First you'll want to place each `node`. You can do this with the command `\node(<name>) at (<coordinates>){<contents>};`. You can use rectangular `(x,y)` coordinates or polar `(θ:r)` coordinates.

For example you can place node 5 at the origin using the command `\node(n5) at (0,0){5};`. The other nodes could be placed using polar coordinates:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(n5) at (0,0){5};
\node(n6) at (60:3){6};
\node(n3) at (132:3){3};
\node(n2) at (204:3){2};
\node(n4) at (276:3){4};
\node(n7) at (348:3){7};
\node(n1) at (168:5){1};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So far we have:

[image]

You want your nodes to have a certain `style`, so you can include this in each node with  `\node[<style>]`, for example,

```
\node[draw, very thick, circle, minimum size=1cm](n5) at (0,0){5};
```

However, since you are using that `style` many times, it's good to give the style a name. You can do this within this `tikzpicture` using `\begin{tikzpicture}[mynode/.style={draw, very thick, circle, minimum size=1cm}]`, or you can create a `tikzset` that you can use in other pictures:

```
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw, very thick, circle, minimum size=1cm}}
```

Now with the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}    
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw, very thick, circle, minimum size=1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode](n5) at (0,0){5};
\node[mynode](n6) at (60:3){6};
\node[mynode](n3) at (132:3){3};
\node[mynode](n2) at (204:3){2};
\node[mynode](n4) at (276:3){4};
\node[mynode](n7) at (348:3){7};
\node[mynode](n1) at (168:5){1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

we have

[image]

Arrows can now be added to your graph using the `\draw` command and referencing the names of the nodes. For example `\draw[->](n1)--(n3);` will draw the relevant arrow.

But you want a special arrow called `Triangle`, which requires the library called `arrows.meta`. So add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` after loading `tikz` and you can use the command `\draw[-Triangle](n1)--(n3);` You probably also want those to be `very thick` so you can add that style to each arrow. Adding the rest of the arrows you get:

[image]

If you prefer, you can add a new style to your `tikzset` to include the arrows.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw, very thick, circle, minimum size=1cm},
    myarrow/.style={very thick, -Triangle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode](n5) at (0,0){5};
\node[mynode](n6) at (60:3){6};
\node[mynode](n3) at (132:3){3};
\node[mynode](n2) at (204:3){2};
\node[mynode](n4) at (276:3){4};
\node[mynode](n7) at (348:3){7};
\node[mynode](n1) at (168:5){1};
\draw[myarrow](n1)--(n3);
\draw[myarrow](n1)--(n2);
\draw[myarrow](n2)--(n3);
\draw[myarrow](n3)--(n5);
\draw[myarrow](n3)--(n6);
\draw[myarrow](n6)--(n7);
\draw[myarrow](n2)--(n4);
\draw[myarrow](n4)--(n7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```